# PHP storing same xml object keys to different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, xml, arrays, object

I couldn't figure out how can I store an xml object to mysql so that the first parent's first key to table1 and the second parent's first key to table2.

if I'm not making sense here is an example:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.0
        )

    [addresses] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [partneraddressid] => 2698
                            [pid] => 4497
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [partneraddressid] => 2703
                            [pid] => 4497
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

so from this object 0->prartneraddressid should go to TABLE1 and 1->prartneraddressid to TABLE2

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out.
I load the xml with DomDocument::loadXML(); and than I get partneraddressid by its position like this:

```
$paid1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('partneraddressid')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$paid2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('partneraddressid')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

after this the I can store them into different tables.